# Condition using multiple variable over a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been trying to remove duplicates elements from a list using delete cases instead of the conventional deleteDuplicates function. I wrote something like

DeleteCases[list,x_ y_/;(x-y)==0] which obviously did not work. How do I iterate over  different elements in the list without using for loops or while ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `DeleteDuplicates`? You can supply a second argument, i.e., `DeleteDuplicates[list,#-#2==0.&]`

Comment: Why not use `Union`?

Comment: @AnjanKumar `Union` will apply a sorting to the list. That's unnecessary if he just wants to remove the duplicates. There `DeleteDuplicates` is sufficient.

Comment: @AbheshekPal asked about removing the same elements without using cycles. And he wrote about deleteDublicates. I thought it is not appropriate for the your task